# How to combine multiple where query in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm studying where queries.
I would like to use two where query. I wrote the below code but I couldn't get any records.
Could you teach me the right code, please?

```
public function band()
{
    $images = ImageGallery::where(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '02')->
    where(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '03')->get();    
    return view('band',compact('images'));
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `orWhere` or rather `orWhereRaw`? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods The first two chars of data in your image column can't be `02` **AND** `03` at the same time

Comment: Try `->whereIn(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), ['02', '03'])->get();`

Comment: @thefallen Thank you very much!! perfect !!! Could you post your answer then I will do up vote your answer.

Comment: @Kamran Thank you for edit my question.

Comment: you could also try:
ImageGallery::where(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '02')->orWhere(DB::raw('LEFT(image, 2)'), '03')->get()